# The Windows SharePoint Services adapter runtime does not have permissions to invoke the adapter Web service

Tags: sharepoint-2010, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013r2

I recently was working through a lab integrating BizTalk Server 2010 with SharePoint Server 2010. The idea  was to have an InfoPath form submitted to an http end point. BizTalk would receive the InfoPath form, transform it, and then upload the form to a SharePoint document library.

This would make use of a send port configured to use the SharePoint Services Biztalk Adapter.

However, when I submitted the InfoPath form, it successfully submitted to the HTTP endpoint, but it did not upload to the SharePoint library. Further digging produced the following error:

> Error details: The Windows SharePoint Services adapter runtime does not have permissions to invoke the adapter Web service. In order to fix this issue, you have to add the ADVENTUREWORKS\BizTalkHost Windows account to the "SharePoint Enabled Hosts" Windows group on the Windows SharePoint Services machine. This operation will allow BizTalk host instances running under ADVENTUREWORKS\BizTalkHost Windows account to invoke the adapter Web service in order to send and receive messages to or from SharePoint sites. The group membership will not take effect until you restart the BizTalk host instance.
>
> This error was triggered by the Windows SharePoint Services receive location or send port with URI wss://biztalkdemo:80/LoanApplications.
>
> Windows SharePoint Services adapter event ID: 12458".

[image]

[image]

[image]

Once I added ADVENTUREWORKS\BizTalkHost Windows account to the "SharePoint Enabled Hosts" Windows group on the Windows SharePoint Services machine facing same issue and infoPath is not able to transfer from BT to share point library and message got dehydrated?

[image]

Other question regarding share point adapter configuration for CreditOrderSharePoint -- in the configure pipeline dialog box, in the processingInstructionOptions box, type 1 and then insert the processing instructions you specify in the xmlAsmProcessingInstruction box -- type ---

```
<?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.21" productVersion="14.0.0" 
  PIVersion="1.0.0.0" 
  href="http://biztalkdemo/LoanApplications/Forms/template.xsn" 
  name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:LoanApplications:http---
  LoansProcessor-LoanApp" language="en-us" ?><?mso-application 
  progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.2"?>
```

So where do I get this information ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ADVENTUREWORKS\BizTalkHost service account also need to be added to SharePoint site:

1.Go to your SharePoint site http://BIZTALKDEMO/

2.Go to Site Settings

3.Go to Site Administration

4.Click on Manage site groups

5.Click on Contributors

6.Add Members...(ADVENTUREWORKS\BizTalkHost)

7.Add \Sharepoint Enabled Hosts

8.Restart BizTalk host instance from the Admin MMC